# Combine characters

Tags: haskell

I am reading file character by character and i want to combine all those characters in one string named fullstr in my code.I need entire file in string form by combining all characters in one string.i have tried that by skipping \n.
Here is my code.

```
module TreasureFile where
import System.IO   

main =  do 
        hdl <- openFile "map.txt" ReadMode
        readbychar hdl             

readbychar hdl =  do  t <- hIsEOF hdl
                      if t then return()                     
                        else do
                        x <- hGetChar hdl
                        if x =='\n' then return()
                         else do
                          let char = charToString x
                          let fullstr = makestr fullstr char  
                          readbychar hdl                         

charToString :: Char -> String
charToString c = [c]                     

makestr :: String->String->String
makestr c d =do

             let e=c ++ d
             return e
```

Comment: You can't use do notation without a monad (like `IO`). Your `makestr` should be just `makestr c d = c ++ d`

Comment: can you please help me by correcting my code??i tried a lot..i need entire file in one string that what i am trying

Answer (score 3):

First of all, this won't typecheck.  For one thing, you seem to be confused about the use of `return`.  Some might say that this function is poorly named, since it seems to mimic the behavior of `return` in other languages, but in Haskell it's nothing more than a regular function.  For example, you can do the following quite easily

```
x :: IO String
x = do
    return ()
    return 1
    return Nothing
    return False
    return "It worked"
```

And if you were to do

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    s <- x
    putStrLn s
```

It would print `It worked` to the screen.  In Haskell, `return` is nothing more than a constructor for monadic types.  It takes a single value and wraps it in the appropriate monadic context depending on the type signature.  So I could have also written

```
x :: Maybe String
x = do
    return ()
    return 1
    return Nothing
    return False
    return "It worked"
```

Then

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    case x of
        Just s -> putStrLn s
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Never reached"
```

Notice that in this context, `x` is matched on just like any other pure value, rather than being treated as an `IO` action with the bind symbol `<-`.

---

The other problem is that you appear to be trying to modify `fullstr` at every iteration through your loop.  In Haskell, values are *immutable*, you can not change them after they've been assigned.  It could be said that Haskell has no variables, only names bound to values.  Here, you're actually initializing `fullstr` recursively, with the expression

```
let fullstr = makestr fullstr char
```

And this computation will never finish, it gets stuck in an infinite recursive loop.  Additionally, you're never returning `fullstr` anywhere, you're just assigning it then moving on to the next iteration of the loop in `readbychar`.  You can solve this problem a lot more simply, if you want to read the first line of a file just use `readFile`:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "map.txt"
    let firstLine = takeWhile (/= '\n') contents
    putStrLn firstLine
```

If you want each line of the file in a list, you can just call `lines` on it:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "map.txt"
    let allLines = lines contents
    mapM_ putStrLn allLines        -- mapM_ is like map but for monadic functions
```

Comment: I tried this code ,it worked.I got my entire file in list form.thanks for that but can you help to get this file in only one string by eliminating \n\r main :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "map.txt"
    let firstLine = lines contents
    print firstLine

Comment: @Hiren You can use a combination of `concat` and `lines` for this.  `lines` will split the entire string by newline sequences (including `\r\n`), and then `concat` simply joins a list of strings together end-to-end.

Comment: i completely agree with you that concat can join string but for that i have to iterate this variable named as all_lines in which all lines in list form.i need to combine it in one string .here is my code:ain :: IO ()
main = do
    contents <- readFile "map.txt"
    let all_lines = lines contents
    print all_lines                                                          this all_lines variable has each file line in list..please help to get this all line only in single string variable.

Comment: @Hiren Simply do `let all_lines = concat (lines contents)`, then `putStrLn all_lines` will print out the contents of the file sans newline characters

Answer (score 0):

This a already written as a library function [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents)

You can use it like:

```
import System.IO (ReadMode, openFile, hGetContents)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    hdl <- openFile "map.txt" ReadMode
    cnts <- hGetContents hdl
    doSomethingWith cnts

doSomethingWith :: String -> IO ()
doSomethingWith = error "You didn't say what you wanted to do."
```

Eventually, you may want to avoid the semi-closed state.  You might do that with:

```
import Control.Exception (bracket)
import System.IO (ReadMode, openFile, hGetContents, hClose)

safeDeinterleaveIO :: IO [a] -> IO [a]
safeDeinterleaveIO act = do
    interleaved <- act
    return $! length interleaved `seq` interleaved

main :: IO ()
main = do
    cnts <- bracket acquire release use
    doSomethingWith cnts
 where
    acquire = openFile "map.txt" ReadMode
    use = safeDeinterleaveIO . hGetContents
    release = hClose
```

Or, you might learn a streaming library like `conduit`, `pipes`, or `io-streams`.